# How to transfer values from one view to another through the controller?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am tryying to implement a very simple Spring MVC application however not interested in binding a bean or model as I simply want to transfer value from one view to another through the controller.

Consider the following:

I have a simple searchForm

```
<form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="POST">
    <input name="test" name="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

I then have a method in the controller which intercepts the post request:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processSubmit(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest)  
{   
    return new ModelAndView("Results", model);
}
```

I now want to read the value submitted in the "test" input so in Results view I have:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <body>

        <c:out value="${test}"/>
    </body>
```

But I don't see the value submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access arbitrary request parameters using the `paramValues` map, e.g.

```
<c:out value="${paramValues.test}"/>
```

This is basic JSP, nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: Thanks got it eventually. You are right, I'm so into trying this with Spring that forgot all about basic jsp :)

Comment: What if I need to read the value from the Spring Controller and not from the Results view?

Comment: @Roy: Then you need to go and read up on how Spring MVC works.

Comment: I have and I am able to do it by binding a model to the form however since I only need to transfer one string I find this meethod a bit cumbersome. I noticed I can add a string attribute to the model map however the form expects binding of an object with get and set methods so a bit confused of how to do it when all I need is to read one string and not a bean